# Simple modules and homological algebra

Tags: ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra, and $M$ an $A$-module. If $\mathrm{Ext}_A^{1}(M,S)=0$ for every simple $A$-module $S$, then $M$ is projective.
I know that this is true if $A$ is finite-dimensional, but if $A$ is infinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, let $A=\mathbb{C}[[x]]$, the algebra of power series. Then $A$ is local, so only has one simple module $S=A/(x)$.Then $M=A[x^{-1}]$ is not projective ($x$ does not act invertibly on any non-zero projective module) but $\operatorname{Ext}^1_A(M,S)=0$ ($x$ acts invertibly on $M$, and so invertibly on this $\operatorname{Ext}$-module, but $x$ acts as zero on $S$, and so as zero on the $\operatorname{Ext}$-module).